# Supply a writable stream to extract a string from

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, node-streams

In Node, I'm calling a library function that takes a stream which it will write the contents of a file to. Typically this would be a `WritableStream` to write a file to disk, but I actually just want the contents as a string.

Is there a simple way to achieve this, preferably without additional dependencies? That is, along these lines:

```js
function getImageContents() {
  const stream = new SomeKindOfStream();
  makeImage(stream);
  return stream.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this worked:

```js
async function getImageContents() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const stream = new Writable()
    let s = '';
    stream._write = (chunk, enc, next) => {
      s += chunk.toString()
      next()
    }
    stream.on('finish', () => {
      resolve(s)
    })
    stream.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e)
    })

    makeImage(stream)
  })
}
```